# Is it possible to show a Progress Bar in a spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I'd like to show a `ProgressBar`/`ProgressDialog` inside of a `Spinner`, specifically the small "loading spinner." Is this possible? How would I go about doing this.

I am filling the contents of a `Spinner` with a response from an http request so there is a slight delay in receiving the data that will fill the spinner. I'd like to show "loading spinner" during the slight delay to let the user know that something is loading.

Any help and suggestions are greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with a `RelativeLayout` and set the alignment regarding by your `Spinner`:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>

    <Spinner
         ...
         android:id="@+id/idSpinner" />

    <ProgressBar
         style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
         ...
         android:layout_alignTop="@id/idSpinner"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@id/idSpinner"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@id/idSpinner"
         android:layout_alignRight="@id/idSpinner" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, use `setVisibility` method to display or remove the `ProgressBar`. This should do the trick.